# UICollection view zooming in (Like goodnotes or notability)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm struggling to figure out how to zoom an entire UICollectionView, take for example goodnotes or notability, there is a list of pages, a UICollectionView is used i guess but i can't figure out how the zoom in is performed, all i can find is ways to zoom a specific cell or changing the grid of a collection view with a pinch gesture. I need the whole UICollectionView to zoom in and out like if it was a UIScrollView

Example of the desired result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvOPdn5b_ms&ab_channel=FabrizioBeccaceci

Comment: I didn't see the apps you mentioned and can't speculate on how it's implemented there, but there are less straightforward solution for this. E.g., it's possible to make an image out of the screen area and show it somehow. Just to give you an alternative idea.

Comment: I've added a link to a video showing the desired result

Comment: I'm afraid the prototype doesn't give the correct impression, as it doesn't explain how it looks on the phone screen. Especially, related to surrounding views, enclosing navigation elements (a tab bar or navigation bar,) and so on. Anyway, I just wanted to give you an idea that might be easier to implement than playing with UIKit. Depending on how you want it OFC.

Comment: *"all i can find is ... changing the grid of a collection view"* -- Changing the grid is what you need to do. A `UICollectionView` ***is*** a `UIScrollView` - so you'll want to use a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and update the layout is response to the pinch gesture.